# Conflicting Newtonsoft.Json nuget versions.

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, nuget

I have a custom nuget package (let's call it Custom.SDK) that was built using Newtonsoft.Json version 8.0.3 (the nuget contains a reference to the 8.0.3 Json dll).

My project.json file originally used 8.0.3.0, but after upgrading my project to .NET Core 1.0, I was told that one of the packages required Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.0.0 - because of this I updated my project.json reference to 9.0.1 (Custom.SDK is still using the 8.0.3 dll).

Now, when I try to build my project, I get the following error:

```
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json' with identity
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' uses 
'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' 
which has a higher version than referenced assembly 
'Newtonsoft.Json' with identity 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

It sounds like the issue is that my Custom.SDK nuget is using the older version of Newtonsoft.Json while my project.json references the new one (which I need for upgrading to .NET Core 1.0).

Is it possible to get around this without updating the JSON dll in Custom.SDK?

Answer (score 6):

Typical case of a dependent binary compiled with an older version, when new one is loaded at run-time, you shall be able to resolve using `BindingRedirect` in `App.config`, as follows:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="8.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>        
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

this would ensure when at run-time it would request for version 8.0.0.0, it will automatically redirected to already loaded 9.0.0.0, please ensure that version numbers and other information like `Public Key token` are correct, read more about [Binding Redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) here